# How make Excel table auto-update formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am currently working on an Excel 'Database' where all employees are listed inside of. The table is meant to store all software licenses/access' that users in our company have.

The way it is currently handled right now is this:

There is a big main sheet called "Main". It has all employees and their department and then there are a bunch of columns supposed to indicated whether or not the user has access to said program. The table is sorted by the employees first name. See picture below:

This is a view of the table:
[image: This is a view of the table]

Now this table is much longer with around many rows and more columns.

The first two columns are their name and department. Afterwards each column is representing a software.

Each software has their own sheet which houses, again, the full name list and department, as well as their role on that software.

The Spreadsheet is supposed be dynamic, meaning if you insert a role on a software sheet, an X will appear on the "Main" Sheet.

The formula currently used in the "Main" sheet is this:

`=IF(IF([Softwarename]!$C3=ISEMPTY("");FALSE;TRUE);"X";" ")`

Now this works pretty much flawlessly when adding roles to existing users. The problem I'm having is when adding new users to the sheet.

Every time I add a new user, the entire table shifts, making all the X's incorrect.

The current work-around is using entering the employees name and department to all sheets at the bottom and their roles within the software sheets. Then, after adding the employee to all sheets, re-sort all the sheets by the first name and then refreshing all the different formulas in the each column in the main table.

While this "works" its really slow, convoluted and I feel like there should be better way to do this, other than using a SQL DB

Comment: `=IF(IF([Softwarename]!$C3=ISEMPTY("");FALSE;TRUE);"X";" ")` What??  What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Various lookups (`VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP`, `XLOOKUP`, `INDEX`/`MATCH`) would solve this

Comment: @Andreas Its meant to put a cross inside the appropriate column if the employee has a role in the respective sheet and column. Its a really weird way to do it. I didnt create this spreadsheet and the creator has since left the company...

Comment: `ISEMPTY("")` will always return `FALSE`, so your formula is: `=IF(IF([Softwarename]!$C3=FALSE;FALSE;TRUE);"X";" ")` Which could quite easily be simplified to `=IF([Softwarename]!$C3=FALSE;" ";"X")` as I see it.

Comment: Why would it always return false? The table wouldnt work as I understand, which it does, somehow.

Comment: `ISEMPTY("")` Will always return false because it is false and it is a static part of the formula. Try it and you will see. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzUx9.png